# Selenium stops after click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm clicking on OK button. Clicks successfully. After that Selenium is not responding. It is not throwing any exception also. When I close the browser window manually then it tries to continue the execution.

Comment: Can you place relevant code?

Comment: did you try to do it manually in website, maybe there is problem in the website ?

Comment: please provide ur code and html portions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same effect, and so I wrote myself a custom Click() method that I call in such cases.

For Internet Explorer, it does a double-click instead of a click, which seems to be necessary sometimes for Selenium to work.

In Firefox, I occasionally got an exception ("Cannot press more then one button or an already pressed button"), so I wrote the following C# code that explicitly releases the button before pressing it (should look similar in Java):

```
public static void Click(this IWebElement element, TestParams testParams)
{
    if (testParams.Target.IsFirefox)
    {
        var actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.MoveToElement(element);

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.Zero);
        actions.Release().Build().TryPerform();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(testParams.DefaultTimeoutInSeconds));

        actions.MoveToElement(element);
        actions.Click().Build().Perform();
    }
    else if (testParams.Target.IsInternetExplorer)
    {
        element.DoubleClick(driver);
    }
    else
    {
        element.Click();
    }
}
```

This doesn't always work, so I only call my custom Click() method when really necessary. This produces stable results on the sites I usually test.